# Cambiar el color de un texto en espefico en css

Tags: html, css3

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buen día, estoy queriendo cambiar el color de código de esa palabra que esta en morado.

Lo tengo dentro de un h2.

Get insights that help your business grow.

Hay una solucion? de que pueda cambiarle sin hacer esto de agregar un id o clase

```
<h2 id="h2">Get <h2 id="purple">insights</h2> that help your business grow.</h2>
```

Trate de hacer lo de arriba y todo mi texto se bajaba.
..
muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Agrega un [mcve] por favor

Comment: `#purple {color: blue !important;}`

Comment: Tenes un `h2` dentro de otro `h2`, reemplaza el `h2` de adentro por un `span`, y en el `css` cambia directo desde el `id` padre ejemplo `#h2 span {color: red;}` ahí solo se cambia el color del texto que se encuentra adentro del `span`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para hacer eso tu html debería ser algo así:

```
<h2 class="h2">Get <span class="purple">insights</span> that help your business grow.</h2>
```

es mala práctica agregar estilos a los atributos id, para eso existen las clases. Tu css deberia ser algo así:

```
.h2 {
/* some code... */
}
.purple {
color: purple;
}
```

si el color no cambia a púrpura prueba colocando en el css:

```
color: purple !important;
```

Comment: No sabía que `!important` era mala practica, agregar estilos a un id es mala práctica, según vi un articulo de la w3c, las clases son utilizadas para estilizar un elemento, en cambio un id es utilizado para agregarle funcionalidad con javascript a un elemento, puedes utilizar ambos en cualquier caso, pero sería mala práctica y por ende tu codigo estaría algo desordenado, por eso frameworks como bootstrap, materialize, tailwind css, etc. Sólo tienen estilos en clases

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haria asi, dentro de un span.

```
<h2 >Get <span style="color:purple">insights</span> that help your business grow.</h2>
```

Si tienes el archivo css externo, ponle una clase al span.

Comment: muchas gracias..!! me sirvio , me olvide por completo de que podria usar el span